Windows 11 24H2 broke Java TrayIcon
Just execute my snippet and see that it prints "Left button clicked" even with middle mouse button.
This issue happens since the last Windows 11 24H2 update build 26100.1876
It works well on Win 11 23H2.
EXPECTED -
it should print "Middle button clicked"
ACTUAL -
it print "Left button clicked"
This problem does not happen with python for example.
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TrayIconExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
            Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("icon.png");
            TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Tray Demo");

            trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
            trayIcon.setToolTip("Tray Icon D

---
emo");

            trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                        System.out.println("Left button clicked");
                    } else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                        System.out.println("Right button clicked");
                    } else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON2) {
                        System.out.println("Middle button clicked");
                    }
                }
            });

            try {
                tray.add(trayIcon);
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                System.err.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("System tray not supported!");
        }
    }
}



Which version of the JDK are you using?

This is a bug and has been an issue since version Version 22H2. Read and follow here. To date, no update has repaired this problem.

@DevilsHnd-退した - That link is to an issue tracker for an archived project.  Don't expect any updates to the issue.

On 23H2 it works well. The problem happen on 24H2.
